# How to get list of fields from a .csv file using SQL

Tags: sql, csv

I need to extract a list of fields from a dynamic .csv file - it can have n fields and n is unknown.

I know I can do something like

```
SELECT *
from [myfile] 
where 0 = 1
```

But that'll give me a row of headers; I need a list in one column.

I'm triggering SQL from within an Excel macro, using:-

```
Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set a = fs.CreateTextFile(csv_folder & "schema.txt", True)
a.WriteLine ("[" & csv_name_1 & "]")
a.WriteLine ("Format = CSVDelimited")
a.WriteLine ("MaxScanRows = 0")
a.WriteLine ("")

Set cN = New ADODB.Connection
cN.Open ("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
    "Data Source=" & folder_id & ";" & _
    "Extended Properties=""text; HDR=Yes; FMT=Delimited; IMEX=1;""")
```

Many thanks!

Comment: Which dbms are you using? ANSI/ISO SQL has no read from csv functionality, so you'll need some product specific functionality here.

Comment: Ok so I don't quite understand what you've asked there, but here goes - I'll edit the OP

Comment: You can't select from a text file in standard SQL. This is apparently something specific to the database system you are using. jarlh wants to know **which** DBMS that is.  "SQL" is just a query language, not a database product. Every relational database is a "SQL database"

Comment: Sorry for the newbie question but how do I find out?